# How to do last-child selector in React native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I use Scrollview and there are 3 views in it. I leave a gap between them.

For example: "marginRight: 5".

But I don't want this gap in the last view. That's why I need this kind of thing. Can you help me?

Comment: React (native) is JS, `last-child` is CSS. So either `.foo-class:last-child{}` or `<div class="{$index == myData.length - 1 ? 'last-child' : ''}">`

Comment: You didn't understand me. I am using the react native.

Comment: const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
    loading: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: Are you using a loop to generate the `View`s? It would help to show some code. If you are using the same style on each `View`, without a loop, then on the last `View` you could do this: `style={[yourViewStyle, { marginRight: 0 }]}`

Comment: I fixed @zaytrix.. very big thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply this you can achive it what are you looking for

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  p: {
    marginRight: 5
  },
  'p:last-child': {
    marginRight: 0
  }
});
```

Edit: Use the component
https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet

Comment: Check it now @Dodis

Comment: I have installed the EStyleSheet package.

Comment: After installing this package if it's working fine please upvote me.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no super-nice way without using a library, but if this is in a `.map()` then you probably want to do something like Justinas alluded to:

```
items.map((item, index) => (
  <Text style={[
    styles.regularItemStyle,
    index === items.length - 1 ? styles.lastItemStyle : null,
  ]}>
    {item.name}
  </Text>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this you have written your html according to your question

```
<div>
  <p>This is a paragraph2.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph2.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph3.</p>
</div>
```

if you have written html like this you can apply this css it's going to work for you

```
div{
  display:flex; /* for one line */
}
div p{
  margin-right:5px;
}
div p:last-child{
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand me. I am using the react native.

Comment: const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
    loading: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,