# Is there any way to use nth-child or :last-child in react-native styled components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, css-selectors, styled-components

I just figured out that it is not possible to use nth-child or last-child, first-child in react-native styled components.

what I want to do is  :

```js
const InputWrapper = styled.View`
  margin-bottom: ${wp(43)}px;
  &:last-child { // I want to do this
    background : red; 
  }
`;
```

Is there any way to use pseudo selector in react native styled components ?

I think I can handle this by passing some props like `isLast : boolean` but I'm still curious about pseudo selector in react native environment .

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you to achieve this. Use the component https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  p: {
   marginRight: 5
  },
 'p:last-child': {
   marginRight: 0
  }
 });
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761808/13680835